# PyQGIS Layout - Change Image Source QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, layouts

Looking for a solution to loop through existing layouts in a QGIS 3.6 document and change a source of an image. The image is the same in each of the layouts. What I have is:

```
from qgis.core import QgsLayerTreeGroup, QgsLayerTreeLayer, 
import os,sys
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
for layout in projectLayoutManager.layouts():
    #print (layout)
    image = layout.itemById("footer")
    print (image)
    image.setPicturePath(r"F:\Documents\Footer.tif")
```

It seems to find the image just fine. Returns:

```
<qgis._core.QgsLayoutItemPicture object at 0x0000016071A895E8>
```

but fails to do anything from the last line:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setPicturePath'
```

Comment: Perhaps there's an `Item ID` that is empty in one of your layouts? Otherwise your code seems to work fine, at least on QGIS 3.8.

Comment: @Joseph You are right. There were some layout in the mix without the image. The rest of the layouts worked fine. Thanks